# How to control USB tranceiver/ HUB power

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, arm, gpio

I am using AM3517 with Linux 2.6.32.8. 
I have to control the USB power from software. I was looking to write some registers to put it in suspend mode. I looked at the hardware schematic based on that the board has AM3517->USBHOST-> TIUSB1210 (transceiver)->TUSB8040 (Hub)->usBport.

I am able to use USB port at will.Here is the part of dmesg

```
usbcore: registered new interface driver asix
usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8187
usbcore: registered new interface driver zd1201
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: OMAP-EHCI Host Controller
ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: irq 77, io mem 0x48064800
ehci-omap ehci-omap.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
usb usb1: Product: OMAP-EHCI Host Controller
usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 2.6.32.8 ehci_hcd
usb usb1: SerialNumber: ehci-omap.0
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
USB Mass Storage support registered.
g_ether gadget: using random self ethernet address
g_ether gadget: using random host ethernet address
usb0: MAC 0e:ed:d6:cc:da:53
usb0: HOST MAC f6:62:10:36:d1:ad
g_ether gadget: Ethernet Gadget, version: Memorial Day 2008
g_ether gadget: g_ether ready
musb_hdrc musb_hdrc: MUSB HDRC host driver
musb_hdrc musb_hdrc: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
usb usb2: Product: MUSB HDRC host driver
usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 2.6.32.8 musb-hcd
usb usb2: SerialNumber: musb_hdrc
hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detected

Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver

usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci-omap and address 2
Empty flash at 0x011102bc ends at 0x01110800
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=8043
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 710208497AA3
hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1:1.0: 1 port detected

usb 1-1: USB disconnect, address 2
```

I looked into ULPI interface but think it is not supported for TIUSB1210. please correct me If I misinterpreted. Or do I have to  change the code or kernel config to enable it?

How do I access the registers of transceiver and HUB? I am open to all suggestions.

I would appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You do not access device registers directly.

You just send appropriate control messages (see section 11.24.2 of the USB 2.0 spec) to the root hub; these messages are then handled by the host controller driver.

Comment: I just responded the solution to the above question in the following thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015028/unable-to-access-bus-memory